# Iterate and extract several lists from a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
dic = {'features': [{'type': 'Feature',
   'geometry': {'geodesic': False,
    'type': 'Point',
    'coordinates': [33.44904857310912, 52.340950190985474]},
   'id': '0',
   'properties': {'a1': 1.313, 
      'a2': -0.028, 'a3': 0.0026, 'a4': -0.025... 
      'a40': -0.056 ... 
   {'type': 'Feature',
   'geometry': {'geodesic': False,
    'type': 'Point',
    'coordinates': [33.817042613128294, 52.340950190985474]},
   'id': '1',
   'properties': {'a1': 1.319,
       'a2': -0.026, 'a3': 0.003,'a4': -0.045, ... 
       'a40': -0.032 ...... 

Almost 1000 ids, e.g. 'id': '0', 'id': '1'...'id': '960'
```

I want to iterate through the dictionary to extract a list of element containing 'a1', 'a2'... 'a40', separately. Something like this:

```
list_a1 = [1.313, 1.319... ]
list_a2 = [-0.028, -0.026 ...]
```

How to get these lists using Python?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you familiar with Python dicts and lists?

Comment: Why not use a `class` instead? This is illegible.

Comment: If you edit your dictionary by adding relevant data and removing the ellipsis it might become clearer what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I am a new Python user. I've been trying to use a loop... unsuccessfully. I can access the data separately by id. Like this:

> id0 = list(dic['features'][0]['properties'].values()).

But it includes all values (e.g. a1, a2, a3 for the first index), not only 'a1'.

Comment: @Steve do you mean a class instead of a list?

Comment: @KarinaMarques instead of ```.values()``` use ```.items()``` for (k, v) pair or ```.keys()``` for the keys. No idea if that's what you asked for

Comment: @KarinaMarques instead of tediously putting things into a dictionary, you can create a `class` of objects. To learn how to handle classes in Python you can start from reading [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp) . If you are not familiar with ***object-oriented programming***, then you should study that first: it is not Python specific, you will need it in most modern languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this. Using [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) makes it dynamic and any number of keys in `properties` will be included in the result.

```py
dic = {'features': [{'type': 'Feature',
   'geometry': {'geodesic': False,
    'type': 'Point',
    'coordinates': [33.44904857310912, 52.340950190985474]},
   'id': '0',
   'properties': {'a1': 1.313,
    'a2': -0.028,
    'a3': 0.0026,
    'a4': -0.025,
    'a40': -0.056}},
  {'type': 'Feature',
   'geometry': {'geodesic': False,
    'type': 'Point',
    'coordinates': [33.817042613128294, 52.340950190985474]},
   'id': '1',
   'properties': {'a1': 1.319,
    'a2': -0.026,
    'a3': 0.003,
    'a4': -0.045,
    'a40': -0.032}}]}

separated_properties = {}
for feature in dic['features']:
    for key, val in feature['properties'].items():
        separated_properties.setdefault(key, []).append(val)

print(separated_properties)
print('a1: ', separated_properties['a1'])
```

Output

```
{'a1': [1.313, 1.319],
 'a2': [-0.028, -0.026],
 'a3': [0.0026, 0.003],
 'a4': [-0.025, -0.045],
 'a40': [-0.056, -0.032]}
a1:  [1.313, 1.319]
```